# Get unique random word from pool each day

Tags: android

I've pool of words (around 200 now) that I want to display randomly each day without repetition.

In shared preference I store the date of last displayed word and if the date today is same, I display the same word that was displayed last time, it today is another day I need to get another random word from the pool and display it.

I've tried to achieve this via two methods:

Method 1: Using sqlite db

- Pre fill a db in assets folder (db has a table with two columns, words and isUsed)
- on onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) copy pre filled db to /data
- use sqlite to get a random entry from db and update its isUsed couter to true
- shave this word in shared preference so that if user opens the app again in the same day then show this word
- If I've to update the words in db then(by 150):

  - create another db in assets folder with new words
  - onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) copy this db to /data
  - copy each words in the original db row by row keeping the isUsed column intact

Instead of using pre filled db I can insert 200 words using SQL statement in oncreate and later update the other 150 with sql statements in onUpgrade.

Method 2: Using shared preferences

- use  to save 200 words
- Create a string with random numbers upto 200 and save it in shared preference
- pop one random number each day and show word with that index. If it is the same day then don't pop but show the last word
- If I've to update the words(by 150):

  - check by how much the words number increased and generate those increased numbers in random order and shuffle it back to the original random string array

So my question is I feel none of this algo is good enough. Is there any better way to achieve this  and if not should I go with method 1, method 1 but without pre filled db or method 2?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just load strings from simple text file in `assets` during `onCreate`/`onUpgrade`, shuffle them and insert into database? Then when you need to know which word to show, just calculate number of days from application installation (N) and show N-th word.

Comment: This sounds best solution to me. I can use orderby random where isUsed=0; sqlite stmt for random word.

Comment: What if the app isn't used one day? The word isn't used, but it's still unavailable.

Comment: Then just increment N manually when next word is shown to user :-)

Comment: @amol you don't need `isUsed` in this case. Just one number.

Comment: @kriomant without isUsed how can I get not shown one next time?

Comment: Words are shuffled just once - when they are loaded to database. They are ordered in database. You store just one number - number of word to show next. Number is initialy zero. When N-th word is shown (or when next day comes), just increase this number. Thats all. No need to mark word as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the Method 1 **WITH** pre-filled table is the best bet. That will helps you in the sens e of expandability and randomness.

Any huge task in onCreate should be avoided, since it'll lag your application. And an SQLLite db will be helpful if you need to increase the number of words later.

The method kriomant suggested is good, but lags the freedom of randomness. We can predict the text after two complete cycles if one sits and tries for it :-)

Comment: Since there is restriction that words should be shown without repetitions, in both cases there is moment when all words are shown. In your case you have to reset 'isUsed', it my case you just reshuffle words and set N=0.

Comment: Your method saves some process cycles towards the end of the lists, yes. :-)